# Ebean 'No service implementation found for SpiJsonService' when trying to store Json in DB

Tags: java, mysql, json, ebean

I am trying to store part of a model as Json in my DB. Ebean is supposed to have this helper :

```
@DbJson
public Map<String, Object> jsonContent;
```

But when I try to store my bean, it only works if I do not give it the `jsonContent` field. As soon as I try to set it, I get the following error:

```
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[CompletionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError]]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:251)
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:178)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(AkkaHttpServer.scala:343)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(AkkaHttpServer.scala:341)
    at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$recoverWith$1(Future.scala:414)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transformWith$1(Promise.scala:37)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:273)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:280)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1592)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1582)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.type.ScalarTypeJsonMap.formatValue(ScalarTypeJsonMap.java:166)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.type.ScalarTypeJsonMap.bind(ScalarTypeJsonMap.java:148)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.type.ScalarTypeJsonMap$Clob.bind(ScalarTypeJsonMap.java:55)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanProperty.bind(BeanProperty.java:648)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dml.DmlHandler.bindInternal(DmlHandler.java:226)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dml.DmlHandler.bind(DmlHandler.java:198)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dmlbind.BindableProperty.dmlBind(BindableProperty.java:54)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dmlbind.BindableList.dmlBind(BindableList.java:62)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dml.InsertMeta.bind(InsertMeta.java:162)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dml.InsertHandler.bind(InsertHandler.java:97)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No service implementation found for SpiJsonService?
    at io.ebean.text.json.EJson.init(EJson.java:31)
    at io.ebean.text.json.EJson.<clinit>(EJson.java:23)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.type.ScalarTypeJsonMap.formatValue(ScalarTypeJsonMap.java:166)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.type.ScalarTypeJsonMap.bind(ScalarTypeJsonMap.java:148)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.type.ScalarTypeJsonMap$Clob.bind(ScalarTypeJsonMap.java:55)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanProperty.bind(BeanProperty.java:648)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dml.DmlHandler.bindInternal(DmlHandler.java:226)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dml.DmlHandler.bind(DmlHandler.java:198)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dmlbind.BindableProperty.dmlBind(BindableProperty.java:54)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dmlbind.BindableList.dmlBind(BindableList.java:62)
[INFO] [08/06/2018 16:03:23.475] [Thread-2] [CoordinatedShutdown(akka://sbt-web)] Starting coordinated
```

My bean looks like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table")
public class MyBean extends AManageableModel {

    public static final Finder<Long, Configuration> find = new Finder<>(MyBean.class);

    @Constraints.Required
    public String name;

    @Constraints.Required
    @JsonProperty("some_property")
    public String someProperty;

    @DbJson
    @JsonProperty("json_content")
    public Map<String, Object> jsonContent;

}
```

When I use the following Json to create a line in DB, it works (and `jsonContent` is `null`):

```
{
  "name": "test 1",
  "some_property": "some property content"
}
```

But when I use the following Json :

```
{
  "name": "test 1",
  "some_property": "some property content",
  "json_content": {
    "test":"test",
    "test2":"test2"
  }
}
```

it crashes (see beginning of the post for full stackTrace).

Serialization is done using Jackson :

```
Json.fromJson(jsonData, MyBean.class);
```

Comment: In general, if your question has not been answered, and the error/problem has changed, it is best to transparently rewrite it. There is no value in adding updates the start, since the majority readers will not have seen the original, and the fact that it has been updated will add confusion (what was the problem before?). If you want readers to see the original problem, then put "update" or "edit" as a title at the bottom, and put your new content after that (this way, things are in the correct chronological order). Readers generally will not consult the edit history to see prior versions.

Comment: Did you figured out the problem? I have the same error :(

Comment: @apflieger I answered this post a few hours after posting it (See accepted answer from myself). Basically, I had to change `Map<String,Object>` to `Map<String,String>`. I suspect the Map needs to contain serializable objects.

Comment: I'm surprised it fixes the problem because the exception was about loading the class EJson, which happens before deserialization. Didn't you change something else like moving the call `Json.fromJson(jsonData, MyBean.class);` ?
I fixed the problem in my code by making a useless call `EJson.write(new Object());` in the application startup thread to force the loading of the class in this thread. I suspect that it's a thread/class loading issue. The loading of the class failed when happening in some CompletableFuture async stuff, same as you

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did not have to resort to pre loading the class, but this was several months ago and I have not worked on this project for a long time so sadly, I won't be able to recall much more. Anyway thanks for your feedback and input, this might be helpful in the future !

Comment: I went back to this project today and I had to go back to `Map<String,Object>` for unrelated reason, and your solution worked... TBH, I feel dirty for using this, but thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so using :

```
Map<String,String> jsonContent
```

instead of :

```
Map<String,Object> jsonContent
```

works for me, so I suspect "Object" needs to extends something that is serializable.

**EDIT:**
So, 2 years later I had to use `Map<String,Object> jsonContent` for unreleated reason and the same problem came back. Here is a dirty solution, call this at applications startup:

```
try {
  EJson.write(new Object());
} catch (IOException e1) {
  e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

This forces `EJson` to load and problem goes away.... but damn is it dirty.